# script that will monitor changes in at least 2 files/directories and execute a third script only when both are modified

Tags: linux, command-line, script

I have two sensors that each create an entry in a text file when triggered. Now I need something to monitor these two files (i can also put them in 2 directories each if that helps in any way) and trigger a third script only when changes occur to both of the aforementioned files/directories. I have found tools like inotify-wait, fswatch, entr and some others but all of these are triggered at any change.

At the moment I'm trying this but it does not work properly:

```
#!/bin/bash
while inotifywait -e modify /home/user/triggerdir/ ;
do
  if [ "inotifywait -e modify /home/user/triggerdir2/" ];
    then
          echo Alert | mail -n -s "test-notify SCRIPT HUZAAAA" user@gmail.com
  else
    # Don't do anything unless we've found one of those
    :
  fi
done
```

thank you in advance for any input/insights :)

Comment: You have no guarantee that as written, the second inotifywait command will trigger as it may already be updated before it's ready. Put them in the background, then wait on them may help. it would help if you told us why it is not working as expected.

Comment: "only when changes occur to both" – If one file changes today and the other changes the day after tomorrow, will it count? Or is there a time window?

Comment: in terms of time window, the changes would occur almost simultaneously, else something is wrong, so it should not be more then a few seconds at most before sensors are triggered and adjust file/directory, else it is faulty